# How to handle superiors who focus on unaccomplished goals and do not provide any help or guidance?

Tags: feedback

This is being posted on behalf of a friend.

The backstory: 
My friend is a woman who works in a Mediterranean country, rather young in age, with no family obligations whatsoever.

She has two superiors, one middle-aged man, not married, no kids, who handles business appointments and sales overseas, and one middle aged woman, married with kids, who she handles inland sales, (I am including these information because I believe they have a role in the power play). Their sales revenues are also quite big in difference, with her male's superior being a lot, lot higher.

So, to the actual problem:
While her male superior provides vague instructions and lets her just wing the tasks he provides for her, leaving the initiative and the actual problem solving to her, supports her and doesn't have any negative comments, her female superior has only negative comments for her work and she focuses on the tasks and goals unaccomplished, provides no guidance, opposes every decision making or initiative taken by her, even hinders her efforts to become a sales representative herself (although her male superior and higher management wish her to become one), one such example is that the female superior created verbal tension after my friend participated in a company organized seminar for sales techniques stating something along the lines "it wasn't her place" etc.

Expanding on the marital status references as requested: My and my friend's assumption is that her superior feels threatened by both her age and lack of family obligations, in combination with the fact that higher management wants my friend to become a sales representative in order to boost their sales,  she fears she will eventually become obsolete and even lose her job in the future. The society is rather close minded there.

How can she handle her superior without confronting her directly and causing a scene (my friend doesn't want that)?

Comment: 1) Is marriage status and with/without kids important to the story? If not, you should consider removing it, if yes, you should expand on that (is there a cultural element at play here?) 2) We are not mind-readers and cannot know why this woman behaves the way she does, so that question is out of scope here, while the last is one we can address.

Comment: @shabunc Genders play a big role on older people in close minded societies. Whether you like it or not.

Comment: You basically claimed that you friend has troubles with on of her supervisors because that supervisor is a woman. Gender issues unfortunately do exist, however any claim should have some grounds.

Comment: @LokiRagnarok maybe not directly, but it is a close minded society for the most prt there and things like gender, marital status and age play their part into considering someone as a threat in the workplace.

Comment: @GeorgeKaf See my answer. I think gender and marital status are not relevant for the core problem

Comment: @user180146 Yes, seen it already. Thank you. It is a rather complicated issue and she feels she tries to walk a minefield there.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I believe she is making  a classic rookie mistake. She found the job after searching for a long time and is actually one close to her field of studies. So, she tries to act as a cushion and just absorb the created tension and bad behavior and not create any more consflicts.

Comment: Has she spoken to her more positive superior about the feedback she's getting from her more negative superior?

Comment: Are the two superiors peers of each other? Or does one outrank the other?

Comment: @PlayerOne They are peers, also she reports everything it happens to her male superior and she tells her not to worry and that he'll talk to her peer.

Comment: If she's doing well, and the more influential manager is aware, then, eventually, she will be promoted. The one being negative is, indeed, probably threatened, but confronting her wins you nothing. She should continue to do the job to the best of her ability, and make sure that the positive manager has visibility of her successes. If the negativity becomes too much, she can approach the positive manager and ask for help and guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I was new in my career I had a superior who was responsible for my day to day activities, and we both reported to a common manager.

My superior at the time was, to this day (more than ten years later), the most negative colleague I've ever worked with. He would shout about almost anything, belittle colleagues to their face and behind their back, and make tiny things seem as huge as he could in order to make himself look like (in his eyes) a hero when he fixed them.

It turned out that everyone senior (even people who he thought of as allies) saw through his act. He was tolerated because he performed well enough in areas that no one else wanted to deal with, but no one actually believed his BS.

I just did my job to the best of my ability, and didn't engage in his attempts at workplace politics. I was promoted twice, while he stayed at the same level he was when he hired me.

If your friend is good at her job, she should listen to her positive senior's advice, and just continue doing her job well. Everyone else will see which person is behaving like a professional.

Answer (score 3):

I will not focuss on gender, age or marital status. Although you are right that in a closed minded society this can make a big difference it simply involves way too many assumptions.

Also I think in the end the core problem is unrelated and it is this: **Your friend has two supervisors who guide her and give feedback to her in completely different ways.** That leaves two options.

1) the advice and guidance given are of different style but do not oppose one another. In that case she could talk to the supervisor who gives negative feedback and discuss about the way of feedback, or simply accept the difference and continue.

2) the advice and guidance given do oppose eachother. In that case a chat with either both supervisors or higher management is neccesary.

Differences in style of supervising might be annoying but is not a problem, slight differences in the advices can also be overcome but if they are in complete opposites you have a problem which needs to be adressed soon.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere confronting and talking is not neccesarily the same. All I suggest is that she talks about the method of feedback without questioning the feedback itself. She should do this honestly and without making any assumptions ofcourse